# Nested routes (and constraints)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is what I'm using in my routes.rb file

```
  match 'trackers/(:token)' => 'trackers#show' 

  resources :trackers do
    resources :locations
  end
```

Is there anyway to nest `:locations` under the match statement, so the URL for locations will use the tracker's token (which is an string of letters and numbers six long), instead of using the tracker's id? Also, I want the match statement to work no matter the case of the characters in the URL ... all the tokens start with 1X, but if someone types 1x I still want it to work. I can't seem to decipher the syntax/regular expression that would make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around all this by simply adding a `to_param` method to your `Tracker` model:

```
def to_param
  token
end
```

Then you can get rid of your `match` statement altogether. All links generated using `tracker_path(tracker)`, `edit_tracker_path(tracker)`, etc. will automatically use your `token` field.

However, keep in mind that even though it's using the `token` field, your forms will still submit the value as `params[:id]`, not `params[:token]`.

Comment: That was my next question ... so, my foreign keys in the locations table, such as tracker_id will still match the primary key in the trackers table?

Comment: Correct, and once you do something like `Tracker.find_by_token(params[:id])`, the `id` field in the returned object will still be the numerical id, not the token.